# Call function only once with LayoutBuilder() - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I'm trying to change status bar icon brightness when height constraints inside `LayoutBuilder()` is `< or = 100`

```
_top = constraints.biggest.height

if (_top <= 100) {
   myCustomsystemOverlaysColorsFunction(statusWhiteIcons: false);
} 
else {
   myCustomsystemOverlaysColorsFunction(statusWhiteIcons: true);
}
```

but I see that the function is called many times due to the `builder` method, So how can I call the function only once when status bar icons need to be recolored?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Maintain the state with a bool

```
bool statusBarChanged = false

changeStatusBar(){
 if(!statusBarChanged){
  statusBarChanged = true;
  //proceed with changing color
 }
}
```

call the above function from layout builder

or you might change the color using MediaQuery

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html

Comment: I understand the bool method but how can we use MediaQuery here?

Comment: Is the layout builder is for whole screen or part of the screen?

Comment: Only SliverAppBar()

Comment: Sorry I ran that..I was mistaken.. lay out builder is your only choice